# How do you simulate an Erlang(k) variable using a programming language?

Tags: java, c++, gamma-distribution

I have a college project in which I need to create a program which simulates an Erlang(k) variable. I am not talking about the Erlang language, it's about a standard Gamma(0,1,k), k ϵ N+.
I appreciate if someone can help me out or give me advice on how to approach this problem in either C++ or Java.

I've written the formulas and theorem that comes with this problem: [link](http://imageshack.us/g/96/erlang2.jpg/)

Comment: what have your tried? what might work? show us an attempt, etc., etc., etc.

Comment: So, you are looking to sample from that distribution?

Comment: can you at least put the formula of the distribution function you need

Comment: Do you need the probability density function, the cumulative distribution function, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://www.ee.ucl.ac.uk/~mflanaga/java/Stat.html

Comment: I've added details about this variable. Can anyone suggest a code?

Comment: What are you looking to accomplish?

Comment: I want to generate some integer values using the Erlang distribution then create a histogram using the results.